# ActiveUP email delete message with UID

Tags: c#, .net, imap

I am trying to delete message from inbox. Message doesn't have **messageId**(it's not gmail)

I've found in this topic the solution

[MailSystem.Net Delete Message, IndexOnServer Property = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160089/mailsystem-net-delete-message-indexonserver-property-0)

However it doesn't work for me.

The code below is simplifed the application works as MVVM light application.

This is how I get emails.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= mails.MessageCount; ++i)
{
                Message msg = fetch.MessageObject(i);
                MessageModel tmpMsg = new MessageModel() { messageType =             MessageModel.MessageType.INBOX, UID = i, Date = msg.Date, Body = content, Title = msg.Subject, Sender = msg.From.Merged, Receiver = msg.To[0].Merged, IsEncrypted = isEncrypted };
                tmpMsg.MessageWasDeleted += tmpMsg_MessageWasDeleted;
                InboxMessages.Messages.Add(tmpMsg); //this is observable collection of MessageModel
}
```

I've tested this code and proper id is added to messageModel object.

Now when I want to delete the message I use this code in model:

```
var imapClient = new Imap4Client();  
imapClient.BeginConnect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mail_smtp_host"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mail_smtp_login"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mail_smtp_password"], new AsyncCallback((res) =>
                                                  {
                                                      imapClient.EndConnect(res);
                                                      //var box = imapClient.AllMailboxes["INBOX"] ;
                                                      var box  = imapClient.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
                                                      Message email = box.Fetch.MessageObject(UID); //this is just to check if proper message is going to be deleted
                                                      box.UidDeleteMessage(UID, true);
                                                      if (MessageWasDeleted != null) MessageWasDeleted(this, new EventArgs());
                                                  }));
```

This method removes the message based on UID(at least it should do it) but it doesn't. There is no error nothing appears.

Where I could make an error? What's the proper way to delete message using ActiveUpMail?